# MYSQL: Creating a table with same columns on remote machine

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table on my local machine which has the same description as some other table on a remote machine. I just want to create the table with same columns, don't worry about the row data.

The table has around 150 columns, so its very tedious to write the CREATE TABLE command. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html - first hit on Google for 'mysql get table definition'

Comment: As @dezso points out, what's stopping you from performing a SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G on the remote machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Remote Machine :

1. Open command prompt
2. Log in to mysql :   mysql -uusername -p -h
3. fire : show create table TABLE_NAME
4. copy whole
5. exit

   On local machine's command prompt, type :

mysql -uusername -p

paste there and press enter

Comment: Why you don't simply connect to the remote DB from the local machine?

Comment: thats not a good idea. Either you need to open the public connectivity of remote machine or have to whitelist the IP of local DB at remote DB. This is very risky in case user forget to remove it. So don't take any stupid chance which can ruin your database's life. Take care of it.

Comment: While you are basically right, there are a number of possibilities to do this securely. VPN, for example, can help, but you can dig tunnels via dedicated jump hosts.

Comment: Yes if both of the db are in same VPC or VPN then its fine. You just need to allow inbound traffic on database port (3306 in MySQL) at remote DB in its security group or just whitelist the IP of local db. But if both db are in different poles , then I will not recommend to whitelist IP.

Comment: As said, I agree, opening up an IP to the world is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL command line on the remote machine, do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable`, then copy&paste the relevant part of the output on MySQL command line on the local machine.